# setting up OpenCV sdk in Android Studio fail to find libraries

Tags: android, opencv

Long story short i'm tryin to set up OpenCV sdk in android studio and i can't get it to work i don't know why i followed every step in this tutorial https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/setup-opencv-sdk-android-studio.html#comment-2740119423
but it doesn't work and here is my log :

```
06-20 09:05:51.563 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to get library list
06-20 09:05:51.564 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
06-20 09:05:51.564 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library list: ""
06-20 09:05:51.564 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs
06-20 09:05:51.564 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to init OpenCV libs
06-20 09:05:51.564 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to load library opencv_java3
06-20 09:05:51.565 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Cannot load library "opencv_java3"
06-20 09:05:51.566 8636-8636/com.example.hamza.opencvtest W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.hamza.opencvtest/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations [i deleted most of this msg i only left the important errors ]classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.hamza.opencvtest-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the opencv-android.jar to app->libs in your project?

Comment: copying the opencv-android.jar to app -> libs is an alternate method to setup the sdk!! and i also did the other method uing only opencv-android.jar and it didn't work...